# Random Reduction Results Without Block Level ThreadFence

Tags: cuda, race-condition

I am writing a simple kernel for Tree Reduction that copies multiple slices of `blockDim.x` elements each to the shared memory array of each block.

The number of slices mapped for each block is a compile-time variable `slicesPerBlock`.

```
template<unsigned blockSize, unsigned  slicesPerBlock>
__device__ void CopySlices(volatile const float* pIn1, volatile float* sdata, unsigned bid, unsigned tid) {
    volatile float sum = 0;
#pragma unroll
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < slicesPerBlock; i++) {
        unsigned idx = bid * (slicesPerBlock * blockSize) + i * blockSize+ tid;
        sum += pIn1[idx];
    }
    sdata[tid] = sum;
    __syncthreads();
}
```

The problem is that the code above results in random output (rarely, but it happens, so far I only caught the mismatches in the release builds)!

I tried `compute-sanitizer --tool <TOOL> ./MyProgram` for `racecheck` and for the debug builds I got no errors, while for the release builds I got so many errors that it actually reported only some of them:

```
========= Warning: Race reported between Read access at void ReductionR1A0<(unsigned int)512, (unsigned int)8>(unsigned long, const float *, float *)+0x580
=========     and Write access at void ReductionR1A0<(unsigned int)512, (unsigned int)8>(unsigned long, const float *, float *)+0x560 [1201312 hazards]
=========     and Write access at void ReductionR1A0<(unsigned int)512, (unsigned int)8>(unsigned long, const float *, float *)+0x5a0 [1201250 hazards]
========= 
========= Warning: Race reported between Read access at void ReductionR1A0<(unsigned int)512, (unsigned int)8>(unsigned long, const float *, float *)+0x540
=========     and Write access at void ReductionR1A0<(unsigned int)512, (unsigned int)8>(unsigned long, const float *, float *)+0x520 [1162680 hazards]
=========     and Write access at void ReductionR1A0<(unsigned int)512, (unsigned int)8>(unsigned long, const float *, float *)+0x560 [1162594 hazards]
========= 
========= Warning: Race reported between Read access at void ReductionR1A0<(unsigned int)512, (unsigned int)8>(unsigned long, const float *, float *)+0x500
=========     and Write access at void ReductionR1A0<(unsigned int)512, (unsigned int)8>(unsigned long, const float *, float *)+0x4e0 [1085354 hazards]
=========     and Write access at void ReductionR1A0<(unsigned int)512, (unsigned int)8>(unsigned long, const float *, float *)+0x520 [1085197 hazards]
========= 
========= Warning: Race reported between Read access at void ReductionR1A0<(unsigned int)512, (unsigned int)8>(unsigned long, const float *, float *)+0x4c0
=========     and Write access at void ReductionR1A0<(unsigned int)512, (unsigned int)8>(unsigned long, const float *, float *)+0x4a0 [930477 hazards]
=========     and Write access at void ReductionR1A0<(unsigned int)512, (unsigned int)8>(unsigned long, const float *, float *)+0x4e0 [930432 hazards]
========= 
========= Warning: Race reported between Read access at void ReductionR1A0<(unsigned int)512, (unsigned int)8>(unsigned long, const float *, float *)+0x480
=========     and Write access at void ReductionR1A0<(unsigned int)512, (unsigned int)8>(unsigned long, const float *, float *)+0x460 [620352 hazards]
=========     and Write access at void ReductionR1A0<(unsigned int)512, (unsigned int)8>(unsigned long, const float *, float *)+0x4a0 [620352 hazards]
=========
```

Anyway, the only working solution that I have found is to use `__threadfence_block()` as shown below (it works even without all those `volatile`s):

```
template<unsigned blockSize, unsigned  slicesPerBlock>
__device__ void CopySlices(const float* pIn1, float* sdata, unsigned bid, unsigned tid) {
    float sum = 0;
#pragma unroll
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < slicesPerBlock; i++) {
        unsigned idx = bid * (slicesPerBlock * blockSize) + i * blockSize+ tid;
        sum += pIn1[idx];
        __threadfence_block();
    }
    sdata[tid] = sum;
    __syncthreads();
}
```

In short, I do not understand the logic behind the observation described above. According to nVidia:

> void __threadfence_block(); is equivalent to
> cuda::atomic_thread_fence(cuda::memory_order_seq_cst,
> cuda::thread_scope_block) and ensures that:
>
> All writes to all memory made by the calling thread before the call to
> __threadfence_block() are observed by all threads in the block of the calling thread as occurring before all writes to all memory made by
> the calling thread after the call to __threadfence_block();
>
> All reads from all memory made by the calling thread before the call
> to __threadfence_block() are ordered before all reads from all memory
> made by the calling thread after the call to __threadfence_block().

But in my case, the values read from the global memory are accumulated in a private register (`sum`) in an unknown order (since the loop is fully unrolled) and the final value for the current thread (`tid`) is stored at shared memory location `sdata[tid]`.
No other thread depends on the value of `sdata[tid]`, at least not before that `__syncthreads()`. More importantly, why does `volatile` not resolve the issue here? How come only `__threadfence_block()` fixes it?

At first, I thought maybe `Float32` and its non-associativeness had something to do with it, but I tested with `unsigned` as well and the same problem persisted.

What am I missing?

Full Example:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <charconv>
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>


#define CHECK(E) if(E!=cudaError_t::cudaSuccess) std::cerr<<"CUDA API FAILED, File: "<<__FILE__<<", Line: "<< __LINE__ << ", Error: "<< cudaGetErrorString(E) << std::endl;

using Type = unsigned;

template<unsigned blockSize, unsigned  slicesPerBlock>
__device__ void CopySlices(volatile const Type* pIn1, volatile Type* sdata, unsigned bid, unsigned tid) {
    volatile Type sum = 0;
#pragma unroll
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < slicesPerBlock; i++) {
        unsigned idx = bid * (slicesPerBlock * blockSize) + i * blockSize+ tid;
        sum += pIn1[idx];
        //__threadfence_block();
    }
    sdata[tid] = sum;
}

__device__ void WarpReduce(volatile Type* sdata, unsigned tid) {
#pragma unroll
    for (unsigned s = 32; s > 0; s >>= 1) {
        sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + s];
    }
}

template<unsigned blockSize, unsigned slicesPerBlock>
__global__ void ReductionR1A0(size_t len, const Type *__restrict__ pIn1, Type *__restrict__ pOut1) {
    extern __shared__ Type smem[];

    const unsigned tid = threadIdx.x;
    const size_t gid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + tid;

    // Phase 0. Init the output tensor
    // Comment out this phase and test the kernel with
    // `sudo compute-sanitizer --tool initcheck ./ReductionR1A0 12345`.
    if (gid == 0) {
        pOut1[0] = 0;
    }


    // Phase 1. Copy the assigned chunk to the shared memory.
    CopySlices<blockSize, slicesPerBlock>(pIn1, smem, blockIdx.x, threadIdx.x);
    __syncthreads();

    // Phase 2. Tree Reduction
#pragma unroll
    for (unsigned s = blockSize / 2; s > 32; s >>= 1) {
        if (tid < s) {
            smem[tid] += smem[tid + s];
        }
        __syncthreads();
    }

    if (tid < 32) { // Handling s=32,16,8,4,2,1
        WarpReduce(smem, tid);
    }



    // Phase 3. Accumulate the partial sum of this block with the rest.
    if (tid == 0) {
        atomicAdd(pOut1, smem[0]);
        // This is bad. For large samples, there will be huge amount of operations forcibly serialized by the atomic operation above across the grid.
        // It affects the final latency of the whole kernel, see [Thread Fence Reduction](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/blob/master/Samples/2_Concepts_and_Techniques/threadFenceReduction/threadFenceReduction_kernel.cuh).
    }

}

size_t GetPaddedLen(unsigned blockSize, size_t wordCount, unsigned slicesPerBlock) {
    assert(wordCount > 0);
    return ((wordCount - 1) / (slicesPerBlock * blockSize) + 1) * blockSize * slicesPerBlock;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    constexpr unsigned BLOCKSIZE = 512; // power of two only
    constexpr unsigned SLICESPERBANK = 8;

    unsigned LEN = 512*8*1024*4;
    unsigned LENPADDED = GetPaddedLen(BLOCKSIZE, LEN, SLICESPERBANK);

    auto *hIn1 = new Type[LENPADDED];
    auto *uut = new Type [1];
    Type *dIn1, *dOut1;

    CHECK(cudaMalloc((void **) &dIn1, LENPADDED*sizeof(Type)));
    CHECK(cudaMalloc((void **) &dOut1, sizeof(Type)));

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < LENPADDED; i++) {
        hIn1[i] = i < LEN ? 1 : 0;
    }

    CHECK(cudaMemcpy(dIn1, hIn1, LENPADDED * sizeof(Type), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    Type gold = 0;
    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < LENPADDED; idx++) {
        gold += hIn1[idx];
    }

    {
        size_t grid = LENPADDED / (BLOCKSIZE * SLICESPERBANK);
        std::cout << "Grid: " << grid << std::endl;
        ReductionR1A0<BLOCKSIZE, SLICESPERBANK><<<grid, BLOCKSIZE, BLOCKSIZE * sizeof(Type)>>>(LENPADDED, dIn1, dOut1);
    }

    CHECK(cudaMemcpy(uut, dOut1, 1 * sizeof(Type), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    std::cout << "Gold: " << gold << ", UUT: " << uut[0] << ", DIFF: " << (uut[0] - gold) << std::endl;
}
```

The CMakeLists.txt script:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)

include(CheckLanguage)
check_language(CXX)
check_language(CUDA)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug CACHE STRING "Choose the type of build, options are: None Debug Release RelWithDebInfo MinSizeRel Coverage.")
set(CUDA_ARCHS "86" CACHE STRING "semi-colon seperated Compute Capability codes without dots, like 62;86")

# Enforce C++17 for nvcc
set(CMAKE_CUDA_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CUDA_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

project(Reduction LANGUAGES CUDA CXX)

if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")
    set(CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS} "-g -G -O0 -Xptxas=\"-v\"")
endif()

if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Release")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} "-O3")
    set(CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS} "-O3 -Xptxas=\"-v\"")
endif()


add_executable(main main.cu)
set_target_properties(main PROPERTIES CUDA_ARCHITECTURES "${CUDA_ARCHS}")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least 2 issues in the code you have shown.

1. Your initialization of `pOut1[0]` in kernel code is unsafe.  CUDA provides no guarantees about the order of thread execution, or the order of block execution.  There is no guarantee about the point at which the thread associated with `gid` of zero will execute.  As a result, it could be the last thread to execute, even after other threadblocks have completed.  In that case you would be zero-ing out results deposited there by other threadblocks.  Instead, initialize `pOut1[0]` in host code, e.g. via `cudaMemset`, prior to the kernel launch.
2. Your `WarpReduce` function is no longer considered valid CUDA programming.  It relies on implicit warp-synchronous behavior, and this is [no longer considered safe](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/using-cuda-warp-level-primitives/).  <--That linked blog gives an example of a safe refactoring in listing 8.

The following refactoring of your code addresses these two issues, seems to produce the correct result, and shows no warnings when tested via `compute-sanitizer --tool racecheck ...`:

```
# cat t92.cu
#include <cassert>
#include <charconv>
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>


#define CHECK(E) if(E!=cudaError_t::cudaSuccess) std::cerr<<"CUDA API FAILED, File: "<<__FILE__<<", Line: "<< __LINE__ << ", Error: "<< cudaGetErrorString(E) << std::endl;

using Type = unsigned;

template<unsigned blockSize, unsigned  slicesPerBlock>
__device__ void CopySlices(volatile const Type* pIn1, volatile Type* sdata, unsigned bid, unsigned tid) {
    volatile Type sum = 0;
#pragma unroll
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < slicesPerBlock; i++) {
        unsigned idx = bid * (slicesPerBlock * blockSize) + i * blockSize+ tid;
        sum += pIn1[idx];
        //__threadfence_block();
    }
    sdata[tid] = sum;
}

__device__ void WarpReduce(volatile Type* sdata, unsigned tid) {
    Type v = sdata[tid];
    v += sdata[tid+32]; __syncwarp();
    sdata[tid] = v;     __syncwarp();
    v += sdata[tid+16]; __syncwarp();
    sdata[tid] = v;     __syncwarp();
    v += sdata[tid+8];  __syncwarp();
    sdata[tid] = v;     __syncwarp();
    v += sdata[tid+4];  __syncwarp();
    sdata[tid] = v;     __syncwarp();
    v += sdata[tid+2];  __syncwarp();
    sdata[tid] = v;     __syncwarp();
    v += sdata[tid+1];  __syncwarp();
    sdata[tid] = v;
//#pragma unroll
//    for (unsigned s = 32; s > 0; s >>= 1) {
//        sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + s];
//    }
}

template<unsigned blockSize, unsigned slicesPerBlock>
__global__ void ReductionR1A0(size_t len, const Type *__restrict__ pIn1, Type *__restrict__ pOut1) {
    extern __shared__ Type smem[];

    const unsigned tid = threadIdx.x;
    //const size_t gid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + tid;

    // Phase 0. Init the output tensor
    // Comment out this phase and test the kernel with
    // `sudo compute-sanitizer --tool initcheck ./ReductionR1A0 12345`.
//    if (gid == 0) {
//        pOut1[0] = 0;
//    }


    // Phase 1. Copy the assigned chunk to the shared memory.
    CopySlices<blockSize, slicesPerBlock>(pIn1, smem, blockIdx.x, threadIdx.x);
    __syncthreads();

    // Phase 2. Tree Reduction
#pragma unroll
    for (unsigned s = blockSize / 2; s > 32; s >>= 1) {
        if (tid < s) {
            smem[tid] += smem[tid + s];
        }
        __syncthreads();
    }

    if (tid < 32) { // Handling s=32,16,8,4,2,1
        WarpReduce(smem, tid);
    }



    // Phase 3. Accumulate the partial sum of this block with the rest.
    if (tid == 0) {
        atomicAdd(pOut1, smem[0]);
        // This is bad. For large samples, there will be huge amount of operations forcibly serialized by the atomic operation above across the grid.
        // It affects the final latency of the whole kernel, see [Thread Fence Reduction](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/blob/master/Samples/2_Concepts_and_Techniques/threadFenceReduction/threadFenceReduction_kernel.cuh).
    }

}

size_t GetPaddedLen(unsigned blockSize, size_t wordCount, unsigned slicesPerBlock) {
    assert(wordCount > 0);
    return ((wordCount - 1) / (slicesPerBlock * blockSize) + 1) * blockSize * slicesPerBlock;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    constexpr unsigned BLOCKSIZE = 512; // power of two only
    constexpr unsigned SLICESPERBANK = 8;

    unsigned LEN = 512*8*1024*4;
    unsigned LENPADDED = GetPaddedLen(BLOCKSIZE, LEN, SLICESPERBANK);

    auto *hIn1 = new Type[LENPADDED];
    auto *uut = new Type [1];
    Type *dIn1, *dOut1;

    CHECK(cudaMalloc((void **) &dIn1, LENPADDED*sizeof(Type)));
    CHECK(cudaMalloc((void **) &dOut1, sizeof(Type)));

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < LENPADDED; i++) {
        hIn1[i] = i < LEN ? 1 : 0;
    }

    CHECK(cudaMemcpy(dIn1, hIn1, LENPADDED * sizeof(Type), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    Type gold = 0;
    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < LENPADDED; idx++) {
        gold += hIn1[idx];
    }

    {
        size_t grid = LENPADDED / (BLOCKSIZE * SLICESPERBANK);
        std::cout << "Grid: " << grid << std::endl;
        CHECK(cudaMemset(dOut1, 0, sizeof(dOut1[0])));
        ReductionR1A0<BLOCKSIZE, SLICESPERBANK><<<grid, BLOCKSIZE, BLOCKSIZE * sizeof(Type)>>>(LENPADDED, dIn1, dOut1);
    }

    CHECK(cudaMemcpy(uut, dOut1, 1 * sizeof(Type), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    std::cout << "Gold: " << gold << ", UUT: " << uut[0] << ", DIFF: " << (uut[0] - gold) << std::endl;
}
# nvcc -o t92 t92.cu
# ./t92
Grid: 4096
Gold: 16777216, UUT: 16777216, DIFF: 0
# compute-sanitizer ./t92
========= COMPUTE-SANITIZER
Grid: 4096
Gold: 16777216, UUT: 16777216, DIFF: 0
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
# compute-sanitizer --tool racecheck ./t92
========= COMPUTE-SANITIZER
Grid: 4096
Gold: 16777216, UUT: 16777216, DIFF: 0
========= RACECHECK SUMMARY: 0 hazards displayed (0 errors, 0 warnings)
#
```

CUDA 12.2, L4 GPU